# Creating javascript regex tp replace characters using whitelist

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which will replace all the characters which are not in the specified white list (letters,digits,whitespaces, brackets, question mark and explanation mark)
This is the code :

```
var regEx = /^[^(\s|\w|\d|()|?|!|<br>)]*?$/;
    qstr += tempStr.replace(regEx, '');
```

What is wrong with it ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you intend to do with `<br>`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) are wrong - they only allow the regex to match the entire string
- The lazy quantifier is wrong - you wouldn't want the regex to match 0 characters (if you have removed the anchors)
- The parentheses and pipe characters are wrong - you don't need them in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- The `<br>` is wrong - you can't match specific substrings in a character class.
- The `\d` is superfluous since it's already contained in `\w` (thanks Alex K.!)
- You're missing the global modifier to make sure you can do more than one replace.
- You should be using `+` instead of `*` in order not to replace lots of empty strings with themselves.

Try

```
var regEx = /[^\s\w()?!]+/g;
```

and handle the `<br>`s independently (before that regex is applied, or the brackets will be removed).

Comment: I think \w encompasses \d also

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `g` (global) modifier:

```
var regEx = /^[^(\s|\w|\d|()|?|!|<br>)]*?$/g; // <-- `g` goes there
qstr += tempStr.replace(regEx, '');
```

This allows your expression to match multiple times.